# Is it possible to zoom with googles geocode api?

Tags: javascript, html, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I can't get my map to zoom in, I tried to edit the zoom property with in the options object, like the normal google maps API but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s possible.
For example using `zoom` attribute as follows:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }
```